# Windows: Programmatically uninstall the NumberPad from ASUS ZenBook

Tags: windows, winapi, device-driver

Now I have this funny program. I bought an ASUS ZenBook which includes NumberPad. The downside of it is that it turns on with a slightest touch on its upper right corner so that I start write numeric gibberish in my code.

This one, disables the NumberPad (must be run as the admin):

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Setupapi.lib")

#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    GUID guid;
    HRESULT hResult =
        CLSIDFromString(
            L"{4d36e96b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}",
            (LPCLSID) &guid);

    if (hResult == CO_E_CLASSSTRING) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Bad GUID string.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    HDEVINFO hDeviceInfo =
        SetupDiGetClassDevsExA(
            &guid,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            DIGCF_PRESENT,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);

    if (hDeviceInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not obtain HDEVINFO.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceInfoData;
    deviceInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);
    deviceInfoData.ClassGuid = guid;
    
    BOOL deviceEnumerated = 
        SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(
            hDeviceInfo, 
            0,
            &deviceInfoData);

    if (!deviceEnumerated) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not enumerate the SP_DEVINFO_DATA.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    BOOL removeStatus =
        SetupDiCallClassInstaller(
            DIF_REMOVE,
            hDeviceInfo, 
            &deviceInfoData);

    if (!removeStatus) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not remove the device.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Critique request**

So, how could I improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Low hanging fruits:

- `L"{4d36e96b-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}"` looks like a magic number to me. If I understand correctly, it is a GUID of NumberPad; if so, make it a properly named constant.

  Aside, it looks like this program has a capability to disable other features (just supply a different GUID). Consider passing a GUID via a command line.
- It would be nice to have an option to re-enable a disabled feature.
- Error reporting is sloppy. Consider using `GetLastError`.